# I'm told I have a bad reputation, but it is simply not true!

Tags: support, reputation, post-ban

My account seems locked. I only ever asked 2 questions, and answered one where I got a +10 up vote. Since then I have not been able to use this site actively. Could someone (moderator/admin) please check my profile?

Comment: [Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h/11868886#11868886) has no upvotes.

Comment: Define "locked". If it's true you only have these two questions, you are definitely not questionbanned; you might just be rate limited due to someone with the same IP asking questions. Are you sure you don't have any deleted questions?

Comment: There are 4 _deleted_ answers. All from August 12 (a couple look self-promotional, two are questions  posted as answers).

Comment: I've edited my answer to let you know how you can get out of your answer ban.

Answer (score 17):

Here are your deleted answers:

- [jquery - get src of image set by picturefill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513138/jquery-get-src-of-image-set-by-picturefill/12111405#12111405)  - Question posing as answer (deleted by a diamond moderator due to flag raised)
- [Formastic Bootstrap Rails Error- No Such File to Load ButtonsHelpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098801/formastic-bootstrap-rails-error-no-such-file-to-load-buttonshelpers/11903679#11903679)   - Promotional answer that does not explain how the library solves the problem (naked promotion) - Deleted by diamond moderator due to 'duplicate answer' flag raised.
- [formtastic-bootstrap installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369883/formtastic-bootstrap-intallation/11903608#11903608)  - Deleted by a moderator for naked promotion without showing how the promoted library solves the issue; (noticed by a diamond moderator because you posted the exact same answer to two questions)
- [How to dynamically alter inheritance in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127069/how-to-dynamically-alter-inheritance-in-ruby/11804440#11804440) - Deleted by a diamond moderator due to 'not an answer' flags raised on your 'answer'; it appears that you're trying to say the accepted solution doesn't work -- that's not something to put in an answer unless you also have the solution.

It appears that you've been answer-banned by the system because you have posted multiple 'answers' that weren't actually answers; they were either naked promotion (with no example of how your library solves the problem), or questions posing as answers, or a comment that the accepted solution does not work.

This is not a 'forum', where anything goes -- we have specific rules and guidelines to help keep the site free of noise and [to keep the signal high](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVF9lZ-i_ss).

At least two of your answers can be improved to be undeleted (the naked promotion answers) by doing the following:

- Tailor your answers to the question asked, by showing how to use your library and implement it for their specific code; as well as disclosing that you're the author of the library.
- Do not post the same text to both answers

Your answer that should have been a comment can be undeleted if you also provide a solution to the answer (instead of just saying the accepted answer does not work).

Once you do that, flag your answers for undeletion and a moderator will look them over and make sure they're ready to be undeleted.